# Iphone Dev : Google Currency Convert read only the nomber

Tags: iphone, parsing, nsstring, currency

I got this result

```
{lhs: "1 U.S. dollar", rhs: "44.5097254 Indian rupees", error: "", icc: true}
```

in NSString with ASIHTTPRequest method.

But I wanna read only 44.5097254 in one NSString. How to do so?

Comment: Take a look into `NSRegularExpression`... I will give you an answer in a few minutes

Comment: You need to parse json and save just the string you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it with the following Methode

```
-(NSString*)getNumberFromString(NSString*)theString{
    NSError *error = NULL;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"rhs: \"(([0-9]*[.]*[0-9]*)*)" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive | NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines error:&error];
    NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:theString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [theString length])];
    NSTextCheckingResult *match = [matches objectAtIndex:0];
    return [theString substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]]);

}
```

You can find more information about `NSRegularExpression`in the Apple Documentation

Comment: Hi AzzURR1 but with this code
i can read 44.5097254   but if the url give me  write 44.5097254.213.000.1  i recived  44

Comment: Ok I see the Problem I edited the answer.This should cover all results now. Pls accept if the answer works(pressing the checkmark)

Comment: forgott to add brackets see above

Comment: the problem is i can read this one 44.3 but i can not read 1.100000.21

Comment: See this Code `NSString *theString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{lhs: \"1 example\", rhs: \"1.100000.21 sample\", error: \"\", icc: true}"];
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"rhs: \"(([0-9]*[.]*[0-9]*)*)" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive | NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines error:nill];
        NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:theString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [theString length])];
        NSTextCheckingResult *match = [matches objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog([theString substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]]);`

Answer (score 1):

That's a JSON object, you need to parse it and then get the values you need.

Here's a nice tuto: http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/parsing-json-on-ios-with-asihttprequest-and-sbjson/